# Concatenar colunas de uma mesma tabela

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, concatenação-de-string

Tenho um dataframe em python com 4 colunas, preciso criar uma quinta coluna com o valor dessas 4.
Por exemplo:

Coluna 01 = valor1;
Coluna 02 = valor2;
Coluna 03 = valor3;
Coluna 04 = valor4;
Coluna 05 (criada) = valor1.valor2.valor3.valor4.

Answer (score 0):

Olá, você pode fazer assim:

```
import pandas as pd

id = date = time = ['a','b', 'c']

df = pd.DataFrame({'Id': id, 'Date': date, 'Hour': time})

df['ConcatColumns'] = df.apply(lambda x: '%s.%s.%s' % (x['Id'],x['Date'],x['Hour']), axis=1)

print(df)
```

Tem mais exemplos na pergunta do SO em inglês:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39291499/how-to-concatenate-multiple-column-values-into-a-single-column-in-pandas-datafra